# How to Perform HTML form action on one specific element in a Form

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I am currently trying to code the Upload into a single form rather than separate by following the example in the flask-wtf documents, yet the HTML form action seems to be sending all the form data to the "upload" folder as shown below. Is there anyway to make the action perform only on the "uploads"? Thank you in advance.

```
forms.py    
images = UploadSet('images', IMAGES)

class ProductForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Design', validators=[Required()])
    series = SelectField('Collection', choices=[(c.id, c.name) for c in Series.query.all()], coerce=int)
    material = SelectField('Material', choices=[(c.id, c.name) for c in Material.query.all()], coerce=int)
    purity = SelectField('Purity', choices=[(c.id, c.name) for c in Purity.query.all()], default=['1'], coerce=int)
    description = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[Required()])
    price = IntegerField('Price', validators=[Required()])
    uploads = FileField('Gallery', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(images, 'Images only!')])
    submit = SubmitField('Add to Display')

views.py
@main.route('/admin/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin():
    form = ProductForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        artwork = Artwork(name=form.name.data, series_id = form.series.data, material_id = 
        form.material.data, purity_id = form.purity.data, description = form.description.data, price = form.price.data)
        db.session.add(artwork)
        filename = secure_filename(form.uploads.data.filename)
        form.uploads.data.save('app/upload/' + filename)
        flash('The design have been posted.')
    else:
        filename = None
    return render_template('admin.html', form=form, filename=filename)

admin.html
{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Publish your design here</h1>
</div>
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
<form action="/upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER` [refer the source](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/)  clearly

Comment: Hi @Navaneethan, thanks for you reply. This question is kind of unclear, so I've opened another post regarding this question, and you've participate in that as well! Once again, thank you.